How to install Rancher Desktop on Ubuntu Server 24.04?
I tried to install Rancher Desktop on Ubuntu Server 24.04.
This is the official guide:
https://docs.rancherdesktop.io/getting-started/installation/#linux
I did every setting before installation.
But when I install via sudo apt install rancher-desktop, these dependency errors happened:
$ sudo apt install rancher-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 rancher-desktop:amd64 : Depends: pass:amd64 but it is not installable
                         Depends: libasound2:amd64 but it is not installable
                         Depends: libatk1.0-0:amd64 but it is not installable
                         Depends: libatk-bridge2.0-0:amd64 but it is not installable
                         Depends: libatspi2.0-0:amd64 but it is not installable
                         Depends: libc6:amd64 but it is not installable
                         Depends: libcairo2:amd64 but it is not installable
                         Depends: libcups2:amd64 but it is not installable
                         Depends: libdbus-1-3:amd64 but it is not installable
                         Depends: libdrm2:amd64 but it is not installable
                         Depends: libexpat1:amd64 but it is not installable
                         Depends: libgbm1:amd64 but it is not installable
                         Depends: libgcc1:amd64 but it is not installable
                         Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:amd64 but it is not installable
                         Depends: libglib2.0-0:amd64 but it is not installable
                         Depends: libglib2.0-dev:amd64 but it is not installable
                         Depends: libgtk-3-0:amd64 but it is not installable
                         Depends: libnspr4:amd64 but it is not installable
                         Depends: libnss3:amd64 but it is not installable
                         Depends: libpango-1.0-0:amd64 but it is not installable
                         Depends: libx11-6:amd64 but it is not installable
                         Depends: libxcb1:amd64 but it is not installable
                         Depends: libxcomposite1:amd64 but it is not installable
                         Depends: libxdamage1:amd64 but it is not installable
                         Depends: libxext6:amd64 but it is not installable
                         Depends: libxfixes3:amd64 but it is not installable
                         Depends: libxkbcommon0:amd64 but it is not installable
                         Depends: libxrandr2:amd64 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I have installed pass. How many necessary dependencies should been installed before this operation?

That desktop you're trying to install is rather old; I note GTK3  (Ubuntu 24.04 LTS is GTK4 not GTK3) but picking one at random I see it available, eg. libx11-6 | 2:1.8.7-1build1    | noble           | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x

@guiverc How to use GTK4? I can't find where to set from the default guide.

You'll need to recompile & build the packages to use a different library/toolkit, as otherwise the result could be rather unstable & would not be secure (ie. to be avoided if used on a network on online).  Either way as I noted in first comment (random pick of one package from your list); its available for your release so return to basics & try using existing package.. ie. resolve the held broken packages then sudo apt update & ensure all lines are present, nothing there that shouldn't be & no missing lines, no warnings/errors etc...
